# Subsititute everything except an specific regular expression from a list in R

Tags: regex, r

I want to substitute everything from a list that does NOT match a given pattern. I am using R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"

The example list I have is:

```
y <- c("D CCNA_01234 This is example 1 bis", "D CCNA_02345 This is example 2", "D CCNA_12345 This is example 3", "D CCNA_23468 This is example 4")
```

and the pattern I want to match is CCNA_01234 where the numbers are not the same in each case but always are 5 digits.

The desired output is:

```
"CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

so far I have removed the previous part to the match by:

```
y_begin_rm <- sub("D ", "", y)
```

but I have issues in recognizing the match with the [^match] expression.

```
y_CCNA_numbers <- sub("[^CCNA_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]]*$", "", y_begin_rm)
```

that produces the output:

```
[1] "CCNA_01234 This is example 1 bis" "CCNA_02345 This is example 2"
[3] "CCNA_12345 This is example 3" "CCNA_23468 This is example 4"
```

It seems that the issue is the numbers specified in the match are looked entirely through the string and not in the exact combination that I want. So the number after the phrase "this is example " is making a lot of troubles. When I omit the digits or place a digit that is only after the CCNA_string it works just fine:

```
y_CCNA <- sub("[^CCNA_]*$", "", y_begin_rm)
```

reults in

```
[1] "CCNA_" "CCNA_" "CCNA_" "CCNA_"
```

or

```
y_CCNA_0 <- sub("[^CCNA_0]*$", "", y_begin_rm[1])
```

results in

```
[1] "CCNA_0"
```

Is there a way to specify the exact pattern I am looking for (CCNA_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])? Also, is there a possible way to do it in a single step (remove before and after the match in a single regular expression)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

**1) strapplyc**.  This uses a particularly simple pattern.  It makes use of `strapplyc` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(y, "CCNA_\\d{5}", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
CCNA_\d{5}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xGy9LYMGyeWATCXB)

**1a)**  If the only occurrences of CCNA_ are before 5 digits then we can simplify the previous solution slightly like this:

```
strapplyc(y, "CCNA_.{5}", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

**2) sub**.   The pattern here is slightly more complicated but using `sub` we can do it without any addon packages:

```
sub(".*(CCNA_\\d{5}).*", "\\1", y)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

**3) strsplit** If the portion wanted is always the second "word" (which is the case in the question) then this would work and again requires no packages:

```
sapply(strsplit(y, " "), "[", 2)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

**4) substr** If the desired portion is always characters 3 through 12 as it is in the question then we could use `substr` or `substring`, again, without any packages:

```
substr(y, 3, 12)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

Answer (score 5):

With base R you could simply do directly from your original vector `y`

```
sub(".*(CCNA_\\d+).*", "\\1", y)
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

Another option is to use `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(y, "CCNA_\\d+")
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

If you have more than 1 `CCNA` pattern in each string use `stri_extract_all_regex` instead

In case you want to match *exactly* 5 digits after `CCNA_` you could also do

```
stri_extract_first_regex(y, "CCNA_\\d{5}")
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

And of course similarly with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(y, "CCNA_\\d{5}")
## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using a package I maintain **qdapRegex** (I prefer this or stringi/stringr) to base for consistency and ease of use.  I also show a base approach.  In any event I'd look at this more as an "extraction" problem than a "sub everything but" subbing problem.

```
y <- c("D CCNA_01234 This is example 1 bis", "D CCNA_02345 This is example 2", 
    "D CCNA_12345 This is example 3", "D CCNA_23468 This is example 4")

library(qdapRegex)
unlist(rm_default(y, pattern = "CCNA_\\d{5}", extract = TRUE))

## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

In base R:

```
unlist(regmatches(y, gregexpr("CCNA_\\d{5}", y)))

## [1] "CCNA_01234" "CCNA_02345" "CCNA_12345" "CCNA_23468"
```

Comment: I guess you meant stringR/stringi? :)

Comment: regmatches(y,regexpr('CCNA_\\d{5}',y))

Comment: @ShenglinChen is there anything you are trying to say here?

Comment: I think they were saying you can use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`.